# Export iTunes music library information (album, artist, track names) to CSV or spreadsheet format?

Tags: itunes, music, metadata, csv

Is there a way to **export** album/track information from an iTunes music library into, say, a **comma-separated values (CSV) file**, or another spreadsheet-friendly format?

I'd like to be able to grab a snapshot of at least basic metadata – being **artist name, album name, and track name** – and copy into a spreadsheet or database software for reference, cleansing, & analysis.  (If you want to call me a music nerd for wanting to data-mine information about my CD collection, go right ahead! :-)

Is there a way to do such a metadata export within iTunes itself, or else might there be a third-party tool that can extract such information from iTunes library storage?  Or perhaps you have a quick & dirty homebrew script of your own you could share here?

I'm aware there is XML somewhere in the bowels of my iTunes library, and I'm a programming nerd too, but I'm hoping somebody has already invented this particular wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure all the columns you want metadata for are visible in the playlist or library you're looking at. Then, select the tunes you want with <kbd>shift</kbd>-click or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click or whatever:

[image]

Then, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. This will allow you to paste what's visible in the iTunes playlist into any sort of spreadsheet you like:

[image]

It won't label the columns for you, but it'll do the trick quickly.

Comment: Huh, didn't even consider that. Nice answer!

Comment: @Kyle I saw the question and actually said, out loud, in my apartment, to nobody, "OH, I ACTUALLY KNOW THIS ONE!"

Comment: I've been testing this out, and it works great for up to a few hundred rows, but I can't get it to work much beyond that. If the OP wants to do analytics on his entire library, he may want to use my method.

Comment: @KyleCronin I'm not surprised. I imagine this functionality is mainly used to do stuff like make liner notes for burned CDs and such.

Comment: Thanks!  I like the simplicity.  If only this feature were more discoverable.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to export all ~1500 rows on my Mac's iTunes library, and all ~16000 rows on my Windows iTunes library.  Also, I used **Cmd-A** (Windows: **Ctrl-A**) to select all rows, instead of the mouse.  I may still resort to Kyle's method to automate this and get at raw bits instead.  Both answers are excellent.

Comment: @Chris Glad it worked out for you. I tried to copy my whole library and ran into trouble - but with Google Docs having a character limit, not with something iTunes related.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on the latest iTunes!

Comment: @Jash Which iTunes? I just tested it out with iTunes 12 and it still worked.

Comment: Was searching for something else, found this. Perfect; always wondered how to do it.

Comment: Still works in 2015 with iTunes 12.3.1.23 64-bit.

Answer (score 12):

You can do File -> Library -> Export Library and get an XML file of your library metadata. From there it would be a relatively straightforward matter for a programmer to convert the XML data into a CSV, spreadsheet, or database.

For example, I made [this quick Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/2221203) in about 10 minutes to get the artist, album, and track names from the XML and output a CSV. Note that it will only match tracks that have all 3 pieces of info provided, and that it requires the library file to be called "Library.xml" in the current directory:

```
require 'csv'

track = /<key>Name<\/key><string>(.*)<\/string>[.\s]*<key>Artist<\/key><string>(.*)<\/string>[.\s]*<key>Album<\/key><string>(.*)<\/string>/

file = File.open("Library.xml", "r")
contents = file.read

out = CSV.open("Library.csv", "w")

contents.scan(track) do |match|
  out << match
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For enhancements/tools to work with ITunes probably the first place to go is 
[Doug's Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/). There are many useful scripts here.

On the page for Exporting Info there is this [script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=makeatextlist) that exports track information as a text file.

> This script will write a discrete alphabetical list of your choice of the Albums, Artists, Album Artists, Composers, Genres, Shows, or Track Names in iTunes to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

One more option: exiftool will also extract ID3 tags from music files.  One of its many options is to put them in a CSV file, one line per input file.  You can also limit which tags it will pull.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a playlist with all your songs in it. Then you export the playlist as a text file. Next drag the text file into Excel and all your information should be organized. You can then save the excel sheet as a csv.